# java: how to get values into jTable from database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, jdbc

I have created one jTable. I want to display the data into table from two different tables i.e. table employee and table intime. I have used two resultsets for this, but it is showing last resultset's value into jTable.
My code is

```
public void showDailyReport()
{
try
{
        Connect c=new Connect();//connection to database
        con=(Connection) c.getConnection();
        st1=con.prepareStatement("select employee_id,employee_name from tbl_employee");
        rs1=st1.executeQuery();
        st2=con.prepareStatement("select intime from tbl_intime");
        rs2=st2.executeQuery();
        table_daily.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));
        table_daily.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));

}
catch(Exception e)
{
   System.out.println(e); 
}
}
```

Please help me to recode this.

Comment: Seems like weird queries to me ... how do you assure that the `intime` for a certain employee will end up at the correct `employee` with those queries ? And it looks like a simple `JOIN` in your query could avoid the difficulty of joining two `TableModel`s afterwards

Comment: Why `DbUtils` not found in my IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are overriding it

```
    table_daily.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1));
    table_daily.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs2));
```

If you want to append add data from second result set to model instead of overriding

Comment: just modify your method `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs1)` to accept `List<ResultSet>` and call it like `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(listOfResultSet)` and then iterate through each result set in this method to populate the model

Comment: I want data from both tables into one JTabel

Comment: That is what I suggested in above comment